Recommended approach to get data from one BoundedContext/AggregateRoot with some additional data from a different BoundedContext/AggregateRoot?
I am thinking of building a modular monolith, using Spring Modulith, and also apply Domain Driven Design (DDD).
I have a question regarding fetching data from multiple modules and what is the recommended approach.
First, here is how I am approaching the design:

Identified multiple BoundedContexts and representing them as "modules" in Spring Modulith
Using a single database, but each module has a separate schema. Each module talks to its own db schema tables directly.
One module may directly depend on other module(s) by calling their APIs. There will be no cyclic dependencies of moduules.
Each module can emit events and other modules may consume and process them.
Module A can publish events which Module B consume and also Module B can publish events which Module A can consume.

At the high level this is how I am planning to implement the application.
Let's imagine this is an e-commerce application and there are customers, catalog, orders, and inventory modules(BoundedContexts).
There are AggregateRoots like Customer, Product, Order, Inventory.
As per the DDD recommendation, only the ID of another aggregate is maintained in an AggregateRoot instead of a reference to another Aggregate.
//module: customers
class Customer {
    private CustomerId id;
    //other fileds
}

//module: orders
class Order {
    private OrderId id;
    private CustomerId customerId;
    //other fileds
}

Now, the question is how to build a Read Model for displaying a list of orders along with some basic customer details (name, email, phone).
Here are a few ways I can think of:
1. Query and Merge data:

Get list of recent orders from OrderService in orders module
Extract all the customerIds of those orders and fetch customer details for those customerIds from CustomerService in "customers" module.
Merge the orders and customers data and prepare the list of OrderDTOs.

Pros:

Relatively simple to implement without introducing CQRS, storing duplicate copy of data.

Cons:

We are creating methods to serve other module needs. For the current usecase, we only need very basic details of a customer.
For some other usecase from a different module, we may need more details of a customer.
We may implement all those variations of fetching customer details or implement one method that returns all the customer details.
Both options seems to be not optimal to me.

2. Use CQRS:

Whenever an Order is created/updated, use CQRS and store an aggregated view of Order details.
Get order details which containers both order and customer info from the read database/view.

Pros:

Optimized for READ operations.

Cons:

Additional overhead of implementing event handlers and storing aggregated data.

What is your recommended approach to implement a usecase where we may need to show data primarily from one BoundedContext/AggregateRoot with some additional data from a different BoundedContext/AggregateRoot?
PS: Some more thoughts and considerations

Using SQL query to directly fetch required customer info from "orders" module is one of the approach.
From the performance POV it is an optimized way, but it defeats the modularity.
If "orders" module directly query the "customers" tables then "custommers" module won't have complete ownership of its "customers" schema.

Regarding storing all the order related data in "orders" database schema:
Usually order related data including current product details(name, price, etc), delivery address, etc should be stored in "orders" schema
so that even if their values change it won't affect the already placed orders.
But, some details like name, email, phone of the customer who placed the order needs to be the current values. In this case it is better to get current values from "customers" module. Or use some mechansim (CQRS) to reflect those values with current values.


PS 2:
The sample application : https://github.com/sivaprasadreddy/spring-modular-monolith
The usecase I am referring to is GET /api/orders API flow.

For option 1, I would probably let the OrderService use the CustomerRepository instead of the CustomerService but that is just a preference.
Here are maybe some other approaches to consider:

create a use case optimal query to directly get what you need: this means returning a Value Object from your Order repository (with a straightforware sql query for example) that will be consumed by your presentation layer.

It is a kind of local CQRS approach (you can find a better description of it in the red book by Vernon).
It is the simplest option and I would usually start with it if I don't need CQRS. (In your case, the database probably needs to support cross-schema queries for this approach to work)

let the UI do the merge by querying the different bounded contexts APIs but this solution is very network chatty from the client perspective

have an intermediary server that compose your APIs (a custom one or graphql if you like it) but that is starting to get very complex


If you have this need to fetch data from multiple repositories for different use cases, it might be a smell that your boundaries are not well-defined.
For example, a thing to consider is the lifecycle of the data you are trying to merge: are they same in both contexts? Do you need to see in the order context the updates that are happening in the other context?
If the order is linked to a shipping address, it might make sense to save the address in the order itself rather than reading the customer's address every time. (the customer might move to another location in the future, but the order was shipped at its old location, so customer's address # order's address)
If you think your BCs are well-defined anyway, then CQRS might be an adequate solution.
Some of these options require discussions with your domain experts/customers (as well as the CQRS option to talk about the eventual consistency), that's why I would not have a specific recommendation since it really depends on your context.
Hopefully, this can help you and not confuse you more :-)

The CustomerRepository is an internal implementation detail of "customers" module and shouldn't be accessible directly from other modules.
CustomerService is the public API exposed which other modules can use to interact with customers module.

Using SQL query to directly fetch required customer info from "orders" module is one of the approach.
From the performance POV it is an optimized way, but it defeats the modularity.
If "orders" module directly query the "customers" tables then "custommers" module won't have complete ownership of its "customers" schema.




Regarding storing all the order related data in "orders" database schema:
Usually order related data including current product details(name, price, etc), delivery address, etc should be stored in "orders" schema
so that even if their values change it won't affect the already placed orders.
But, some details like name, email, phone of the customer who placed the order needs to be the current values. In this case it is better to get current values from "customers" module. Or use some mechansim (CQRS) to reflect those values with current values.



For a simular usecase i went with option 1, but plainly reusing the "public" DTO of the other module you'd want to use.
Pjotr describes this in his sample implementation: https://piotrminkowski.com/2023/10/13/guide-to-modulith-with-spring-boot/
public record DepartmentDTO(Long id,
                            Long organizationId,
                            String name,
                            List<EmployeeDTO> employees) {
    public DepartmentDTO(Long id, Long organizationId, String name) {
        this(id, organizationId, name, new ArrayList<>());
    }
}

In this case, there's an getDepartment operation, which internally calls and getEmployee method.

Subscribe to the OrderCreated message in the Customer module and import the desired data from the order into the Customer schema. This approach avoid different teams coupling

How this really help? In fact, my requirement is exactly the opposite of what you are proposing. I need to get some basic Customer info into Order DTO for presentation, not the other way around.

You are right, I understood It wrongly, but I guess thst the same solution can be applied in the scenario that you expose, subscribing to Customer messages in order to import the customers informatión in the orders database.
